Tag for "verifying software download during installation"
We have now a number of questions about how to verify release binaries during the installation process. Perhaps there are enough to start using a tag for that.
What do you think about release-verification, or perhaps release-binary-verification? Open to  better suggestions!

Is this about calculating a file hash?

Yeah, or rather the process of verifying that they received the actual release binaries

I like release-verification since it pretty succinctly wraps up the intention of the tag.  My only (slight) concern is that it may not be obvious to users asking how to hash a binary that this is the tag to use.  But then, that's arguable for all tags, I suppose.
As long as the guidance is clear, it should be A Good Thing™
